# Wordpress motion theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress-theming

Right now I'm trying to modify the motion theme for Wordpress. As of now I'm not sure if it's the theme are the wordpress app that is highlighting my tables on a mouseover. I was wondering if anybody had any idea how to remove the table highlighting mouse over feature in a wordpress app using the Motion theme.

Comment: An example link would be helpful to determine the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the theme... I analysed the preview: http://wp-themes.com/motion/

Try to search the source-code of that page (Ctrl + U) for

```
table tr:hover td
```

If you want to change this definition, search through all your theme files. You could use Notepad++ for that, for example...

Answer (score 0):

I am running one site with this theme but I do not quite understand what mouseover effect you are referring to.

Generally, you should determine the CSS rules that are applied to the element:

1. in Chrome browser, right click the element, choose "inspect element" (or similar function in any other browser, Chrome is very good at this)
2. if needed, locate the element in the tree on the left (sometimes the right click picks another element)
3. look at the CSS in the "Styles" acoordion-style table on the right side, expand Computed Style and locate a rule that handles a "hover" modifier. Determine the rules that specify this behavior and path to the CSS file.
4. modify the CSS - remove the rules that are applied on hover